# SQL SELECT with JOIN and PARTITION

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

in my project I got 2 tables (postgresql) - partners and campaigns. Each partner may have many campaigns, but each campaign may have only one partner. The data looks like the following:

```
partners:
id | name
=========
1    Partner_1
2    Partner_2    


campaigns:
id | name   | partner_id | started_at  
=============================================================
1    camp_1    1            2022-07-06 00:00:00.000000 +00:00
2    camp_2    1            2022-07-07 00:00:00.000000 +00:00  
3    camp_3    2            2022-08-08 00:00:00.000000 +00:00
4    camp_4    2            2022-08-09 00:00:00.000000 +00:00
```

The task is for each partner select only 1 campaign with the most recent started_at date. So the final result would look like the following:

```
partner_name | campaign_started_at
==================================
Partner_1      2022-07-07 00:00:00.000000 +00:00
Partner_2      2022-08-09 00:00:00.000000 +00:00
```

For these purposes I guess I need to use a window function with select subquery and Group By statements and I tried the following:

```
SELECT public.partners.name, 
       public.campaigns.started_at as camp_started_at, 
       rank() OVER (PARTITION BY public.partners.name ORDER BY public.campaigns.started_at DESC)
FROM public.partners 
  JOIN campaigns ON campaigns.partner_id = partners.id 
GROUP BY partners.name, public.campaigns.started_at;
```

but it did not produce the desired result. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `MAX()` and `GROUP BY partners.name` to get your desired output. The window function `RANK() OVER()` is expensive and overkill here.

```
SELECT public.partners.name
     , MAX(public.campaigns.started_at) as camp_started_at 
  FROM public.partners 
  JOIN campaigns ON campaigns.partner_id = partners.id 
 GROUP BY partners.name
;
```

Answer (score 0):

On Postgres, we don't even need to use `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` for this, we can just use `DISTINCT ON`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.id) p.name AS partner_name,
                          c.started_at AS campaign_started_at
FROM partners p
INNER JOIN campaigns c ON c.partner_id = p.id
ORDER BY p.id, c.started_at DESC;
```